# build failed with substrate chain on rocksdb in linux

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, blockchain, compilation, rocks-db

I followed this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain/. I got the below error when run cargo build --release. How can I fix it?

```
cargo build -v --release    
       
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: Assembler messages:
warning: Error: can't open /tmp/ccSCYXdI.s for reading: No such file or directory

error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.8.0+7.4.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-aabd480a2f3b76e0/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=rocksdb/
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/cache_reservation_manager.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache_reservation_manager.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/cache_key.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache_key.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/cache_entry_roles.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache_entry_roles.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/fast_lru_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/fast_lru_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/lru_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/lru_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/compressed_secondary_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/compressed_secondary_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/cache/sharded_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/sharded_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_fetcher.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_fetcher.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_addition.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_addition.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_builder.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_builder.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_garbage.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_garbage.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_meta.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_meta.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_reader.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_reader.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_garbage_meter.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_garbage_meter.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_format.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_format.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_sequential_reader.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_sequential_reader.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_writer.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_writer.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_source.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_source.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/blob/prefetch_buffer_collection.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/prefetch_buffer_collection.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/builder.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/builder.cc"
  exit status: 0
  
  cargo:warning=Assembler messages:
  cargo:warning=Error: can't open /tmp/ccSCYXdI.s for reading: No such file or directory
  exit status: 1
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_compaction_flush.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_compaction_flush.cc"
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-a13da7712a385c02/out/rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_job.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/compaction/compaction_job.cc" with args "c++" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).
```

Comment: Maybe you could post the full log here?

Comment: I have exactly the same error on Debian machine: https://github.com/rust-rocksdb/rust-rocksdb/issues/707

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the -v in the build command? Use only `cargo build --release`

I suggest you to install again all the [Rust Toolchain](https://docs.substrate.io/install/rust-toolchain/) and the [Linux development environment](https://docs.substrate.io/install/linux/)

Comment: cargo --help , -v  its ok for verbosity. both toolchain and environment are ok  , though the environment for arch based is incomplete . you must set two env OPENSSL_LIB_DIR and OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR . i think recently for arch based need to have another env variables.